# Directory to use in ASP.NET Core Module in-process hosting SetBasePath

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What is the correct parameter to pass to `SetBasePath` for in-process hosting?

We set the configuration this way:

```
private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
    .Build();
```

However, with ASP.NET Core 2.2 in-process hosting, `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns `C:\Program Files\IIS Express` instead of my application root directory.

**Edit:**

I am initializing my configuration in `Program.Main` in order to read the settings to pass to Serilog, following the [example](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-docker/blob/master/web-sample/src/Program.cs).

**Answer:**

This question has sadly been marked as a duplicate, thus answering in the question instead.

The issue is [discussed here](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/9865). The GetCurrentDirectory will give the same value as out of process hosting in the next update to ASP.NET Core. Meanwhile, the following code is provided as a workaround.

```
using System;

namespace SampleApp
{
    internal class CurrentDirectoryHelpers
    {
        internal const string AspNetCoreModuleDll = "aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll";

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(AspNetCoreModuleDll)]
        private static extern int http_get_application_properties(ref IISConfigurationData iiConfigData);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct IISConfigurationData
        {
            public IntPtr pNativeApplication;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            public string pwzFullApplicationPath;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            public string pwzVirtualApplicationPath;
            public bool fWindowsAuthEnabled;
            public bool fBasicAuthEnabled;
            public bool fAnonymousAuthEnable;
        }

        public static void SetCurrentDirectory()
        {
            try
            {
                // Check if physical path was provided by ANCM
                var sitePhysicalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sitePhysicalPath))
                {
                    // Skip if not running ANCM InProcess
                    if (GetModuleHandle(AspNetCoreModuleDll) == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    IISConfigurationData configurationData = default(IISConfigurationData);
                    if (http_get_application_properties(ref configurationData) != 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    sitePhysicalPath = configurationData.pwzFullApplicationPath;
                }

                Environment.CurrentDirectory = sitePhysicalPath;
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the default hosting method in IIS for ASP.NET Core in previous version. ASP.NET Core Module in IIS acts as a proxy to the out-of-process Kestrel server.

Comment: Give it a go with [`AppContext.BaseDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.basedirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2) - It's used in ASP.NET Core itself.