# How do I get useful debug information from a dotnetcore application deployed to Azure Web Services?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

My appsettings.json is as follows:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I then deploy through visual studio, targeting framework netcoreapp3.0 with deployment mode as Self-Contained.

My azure service reports the following issue:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028526
```

The application logs contain the issue:

```
Application 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to start. Exception message:
Application arguments are empty.
Process Id: 4516.
File Version: 13.0.19218.0. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2. Commit: 4a42afc5aea63750638e118560d43db04bd9ccc2
```

However, I don't have application arguments since this is a web application. Could anyone please advise on how to get useful output from Azure Web Services that contain what actually went wrong?

Comment: The properties panel in Az Portal for your web app should include a debugging section.  Turn debugging on then point VS at Azure and tell it to debug the web app.  Might catch a startup error.. dunno.

Comment: "Application arguments are empty" usually indicates errors in your web.config file. Edit your question to include that please.

Comment: My application does not have a web.config file, as it's an aspnetcore project. I have included my appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to troubleshoot this problem , you can try below by debugging it.

Try including AspNetCore.Middleware to your project. To learn more about ASP.NET Core (2.2.0) Middleware, refer to ASP.NET Core [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Additionally you can refere below threads for more clarity:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6111

[How to fix error "ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939860/how-to-fix-error-ancm-in-process-handler-load-failure)

https://forums.asp.net/t/2154155.aspx?Asp+Net+Core+2+2+HTTP+Error+500+0+ANCM+In+Process+Handler+Load+Failure

[Directory to use in ASP.NET Core Module in-process hosting SetBasePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628995/directory-to-use-in-asp-net-core-module-in-process-hosting-setbasepath)

Hope it helps.